# Sketch the polar graph $r=e^{-2\phi}$

Tags: polar-coordinates

How are you supposed to sketch this type of polar graph?

Are you supposed to somehow relate this to $\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ but can polar graphs even have an imaginary axis?!

I am thinking that you relate it to $\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ because $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$.

I have also sketched the graph plotting each point individually $\phi= 0, \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi. $ $r=1,0.35,0.12,0.04...$  But seems to plot the Cartesian graph. If you want to see the answer on the mark scheme it is [here](http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/57748-mark-scheme-january.pdf) Q4(i) page 24.

Comment: If the angle is just a real value, I don't see how complex numbers relate to this problem. The graph is essentially a spiral, that converges to the Origin. (At a finite length, but that's just on the side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** note that the distance from the point $P=(r,\phi)$ to the origin, that is, the value of $r$, varies with the angle $\phi$.

So when the point circle around the origin its distance varies also.